# Select SQL statement group by and sum two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an sql statement which I cant get the structure right on, when I run what I currently have It says syntax wrong.  I am looking the result to look like this:-

[image: Valid XHTML]
<sub>(source: [churchcom.co.uk](http://www.churchcom.co.uk/test/Capture2.JPG))</sub>
.

This is my query so far but I dont think I am on the right track at all.

```
SELECT        Name, ValueofTaught, Amount  
FROM            Activities
WHERE        (Department = @Department)
ORDER BY Name
GROUP BY BurnhamGrade
(SUM ValueofTaught AND Amount
WHERE Departmetn = @Department)
```

Structure of the activities Table is like this:-

[image: Valid XHTML]
<sub>(source: [churchcom.co.uk](http://www.churchcom.co.uk/test/Capture3.JPG))</sub>
.

Comment: What type of database are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server) ?  Can you show us a sample from the actual `Activities` table?

Comment: I am using SQL Server

Comment: "which isn't working" _in what way_? people aren't psychic. what do you expect to see? what do you see instead? where is the actual data?

Comment: @underscore_d I have tried to show an image of the expected result but it wont show up.

Comment: Describe the structure of activities table.

Comment: And when you say it's not working, how? Do you get an error? Do you get output, but not what you want? The phrase "it isn't working" is the bane of the IT support world because it conveys no useful information to work with.

Comment: @underscore_d Sorry when I say it isn't working, I mean I have structure my sql query wrong and I get no results just an error to say wrong syntax.

Comment: @I_am_Batman  Structure of activities tables added

Comment: For future reference: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Try what user212514 suggested. Brackets around the first `WHERE` are unnecessary. `GROUP BY` goes before `ORDER BY`. `SUM()` and other aggregates need `SELECT`ed at the top with everything else, not added to the `GROUP` clause. Incidentally, if unlike now, you later _do_ need to filter after grouping, you must use `HAVING`, as `WHERE` is pre-group. Finally, note it's unlikely any query will show you the multiple levels of grouping that a PivotTable does, but that's where the role of the database ends and the role of an application such as (the great, free) SQL Server Reporting Services begins.

Answer (score 2):

It sort of sounds like you're looking to `group by` two columns.  I'm assuming the `Value of Taught` column is what gets rolled up for hours:

```
SELECT        Department, Name, SUM([Value of Taught]) Hours, SUM(Amount) Pay
FROM          Activities
GROUP BY      Department, Name
ORDER BY      Department, Name
WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: Maybe a `WITH rollup` after the group by would be something to add to this.